# eslint don't deal with multiple package.json

Tags: javascript, npm, atom-editor, eslint, lint

My project have two package.json

```
root folder

└ app ---- /public
         └ /styles
         └ /src
         └ package.json
         └ eslintrc.json
         └ webpack.config.js

└ server - /something
         └ /something

└ package.json
└ ...etc
```

atom editor shows lint error

```
import React from 'react';
// 'react' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S react' to add it (import/no-extraneous-dependencies)
```

In package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/chart.js": "^2.6.8",
  "@types/react": "^16.0.10",
  "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.1",
  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
  "chart.js": "2.6.0",
  "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
  "history": "4.7.2",
  "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
  "react": "^15.6.1",
  "react-chartjs-2": "2.6.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
  "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
  "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
  "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
  "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1"
},
```

and in eslintrc.json

```
module.exports = {
  "extends": "airbnb",

  "env": {
     "browser": true,
     "node": true
   },

  "rules": {
     "no-mixed-operators": [2, { "allowSamePrecedence": true }],
     "react/no-find-dom-node": 1,
     "react/no-string-refs": 1,
     "react/no-unused-prop-types": 1, // TODO: enable
     "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 1, // TODO: enable
     "no-plusplus": 1, // TODO: enable
     "no-console": 0, // TODO: enable
     "no-alert": 0,
     "max-len": ["error", 120],
     "no-underscore-dangle": ["error", { "allow": ["_isMounted"] }],
     "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true}],
  },
};
```

I think that eslint recognize package.json in root folder as standard.
But I want that it ignores package.json in root folder and recognize package.json in src folder.

How can I do?

Comment: Hi Buddy 
First i'll ask one question from you.Why are you using eslint now?
If it's only for linting purpose then i would like to suggest you to use standard js instead of eslint.That will save your time and you can fix small bugs by typing simple command `standard --fix`...

Comment: @ShravanJain I don't know standard.js yet. I will try

Comment: i just integrated Standard JS with my project. It's awesome. Here you don't need to define the rules for linting and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem myself.

Added "packageDir": "./src" in .eslintrc.json

```
"rules" : {
   ""import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"devDependencies": true, "packageDir": "./src"}],
```

Answer (score 6):

This may be unrelated, but the first item I'd note is that you might need to rename your ESLint configuration from `eslintrc.json` to `.eslintrc.json` (with a dot before the name). May not be the source of the trouble, but could possibly be interfering with the hierarchical resolution. You can look into the multiple configuration extension formats here: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats.

Regarding the `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` rule specifically, I think the configuration option you might be looking for is `packageDir`. Quoting the docs in their repo:

> Also there is one more option called `packageDir`, this option is to specify the path to the folder containing `package.json` and is relative to the current working directory.
>
> `"import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["error", {"packageDir": './some-dir/'}]`

Hope this helps!

*Source:*

https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-extraneous-dependencies.md